# Python's function scope

Tags: python, scope

I am working with python and doing the following.

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]

def function1():
  print(x)

function1()
```

I would think that I would get the error `name 'x' is not defined` but I do not, it prints the variable x even though it is not defined in the function. Why does python let me use variables that are defined outside of a function inside a function even though they have different scopes?

Comment: Because Python uses nested scopes.

Comment: read my answer here > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067976/basic-python-function-and-outputs/26068060#26068060

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are setting x to a global variable.

```
x = "myString"

function global():
    print(x) // Global


function notglobal():
    y = "myOtherString"
    print(y) // Not Global

class myClass: 
    z = "notGlobal" // Not Global

    function printZ():
        print(z) // Global To class

print(z) // Not global so will error out
```

Comment: how do choose a variable to be global or not?

Comment: If its outside a class/function its global

Comment: can you edit you answer to explain a little better?

Comment: There ya go. Should be updated i hope it explains

Answer (score 0):

`x` is global, which means all functions can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I like the treatment offered by [this blog post](http://foreigngods.com/blog/2013/09/14/26/python-exhibits-behavior-similar-to-javascripts-variable-hoisting/), which compares the described behaviour to Javascript's variable hoisting (although the blog uses the negative example to demonstrate it).